# Create query if not existing with get_or_create not working

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I am builing a Q/A where users can vote.

I have two models, **Topic** which deal with the votes and question and **VoteUser** that set a boolean to True when a user vote.

```
def upvote(request, qa_id):
    qa = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=qa_id)
    vote = VoteUser.objects.get_or_create(author=request.user, topic=qa_id)
    vote = get_object_or_404(VoteUser, author=request.user, topic=qa_id)

    if vote.vote_status == False:
        qa.votes += 1
        qa.save()
        vote.vote_status = True
        vote.save()
```

But when I tried the request it gives me an error :

> ValueError at /qa/59/upvote
>   Cannot assign "59": "VoteUser.topic" must be a "Topic" instance.

Comment: Please provide the error. Anyhow, you don't need the line where you get_object_or_404 on VoteUser since you have vote already in the line before where you create it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have added the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to assign an ID to `topic` instead of a Topic instance. This should work:

```
def upvote(request, qa_id):
    qa = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=qa_id)
    vote, _ = VoteUser.objects.get_or_create(author=request.user, topic=qa)

    if vote.vote_status == False:
        qa.votes += 1
        qa.save()
        vote.vote_status = True
        vote.save()
```

Comment: It gives me a "'tuple' object has no attribute 'vote_status'" error matching the line "if vote.vote_status == False:"